# ERROR ReferenceError: KEYUTIL is not defined

Tags: identityserver4

I have been following [this](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/11/implementing-openid-implicit-flow-using-openiddict-and-angular/) tutorial and so far so good except that I keep getting this error after a successful login or what seems like it

```
ERROR ReferenceError: KEYUTIL is not defined
at OidcSecurityValidation.validate_signature_id_token (oidc.security.validation.ts:152)
at SafeSubscriber._next (oidc.security.service.ts:116)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1084
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1144
next @ core.es5.js:4778
schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3851
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3837
NgZone.triggerError @ core.es5.js:4209
onHandleError @ core.es5.js:4170
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:194
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:486
```

I tried the approach specified in the tutorial that didnt work. I imported the file this way `import "./assets/jsrsasign.min.js"` in vendor.ts it didnt help either.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is what I did to get through. If you are using webpack 2 (that is what I am using)

add the following (depending on your folder arrangements)

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
       { from: './angularApp/assets/*.*', to: 'assets/', flatten: true }
    ]),
```

and then referencing in my index.html like this

```
<script src="assets/jsrsasign.min.js"></script>
```

the last line in the  section